# Is there a better way to collapse this navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm wondering is there better way to collapse the navbar shown on this page http://reportalert.info/index-test.php

Because when it collapses it splits onto two lines and it doesn't look great because of the border on the right of each list item. Is there a way that the list items can appear on the same line when collapsed or is there another way I can make it look better when It's viewed on a smaller screen.

Also when hovering over the links it's not the same height as the navbar, i've tried changing the padding but that creates a vertical scroll bar on the mobile layout, how do i go about fixing this.

Here is the code that I have for the navbar:

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #B0B0B0, #797979);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#B0B0B0), to(#797979));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #B0B0B0, #797979);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #B0B0B0, #797979);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #B0B0B0, #797979);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border:0;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#B0B0B0', endColorstr='#797979', GradientType=0);
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li {
    padding:0 8px;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    font-size:19px;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    font-family: 'RBNo21b-Book';
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    }

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding:13px 19px 15px 19px;
    } 

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover {    
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #797979, #B0B0B0);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#797979), to(#B0B0B0));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #797979, #B0B0B0);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #797979, #B0B0B0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #797979, #B0B0B0);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border:0;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#797979', endColorstr='#B0B0B0', GradientType=0);
    *zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    color:#fff;
    padding:0 8px;
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm kind of unclear on your issue, By collapse are you talking about drop down menus? Can you provide a jsfiddle, recreating the specific problem?

Comment: I think OP means collapse in the context of the browser zooming in and out. I would suggest not using the zoom property unless you are aiming to work with people who are using IE 6 (which there are not many people still using that).

Comment: What I mean is that when you re size the browser the navbar splits on two lines but because there is a border on the right of each list item it doesn't look good when the browser window is re sized. I wanted to know if there is a way that the list item can stay on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the hovering, go the way with the padding:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    padding:15px 19px 15px 19px;
}
```

To fix the scrollbar just override the max-height of .navbar-collapse

```
.navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 100%;
}
```